# duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed - R

Tags: r, r-rownames

So, I am new in R and trying to implement a differential gene expression analysis.
I'm trying to store gene names as rownames so that I can create a DGEList object.

```
asthma <- read.csv("Asthma_3 groups-Our study gene expression.csv")
head(asthma, 10)
dim(asthma)

asthma <- na.omit(asthma)
distinct(asthma)

countdata <- asthma[,-1]

head(countdata)
rownames(countdata) <- asthma[,1]
'''
I am getting this error:

Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

Comment: As the error mentioned, `data.frame` won't allow duplicate row names.  You may need to convert to `matrix` or add as a column

Answer (score 0):

The first column in `asthma` likely has duplicate values. Two options I can think of

1. Can the first column be combined with another column to generate a new column with unique values that can be used as the rownames?
2. If not, you can probably use `make.names()`.

Here is a reproducible example.

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c('A', 'A', 'B'), col2 = c(1, 2, 3))
df
```

That defines a data.frame that looks like this

```
  col1 col2
1    A    1
2    A    2
3    B    3
```

The data.frame by default has rownames 1, 2, 3. If you try this

```
rownames(df) = df[,1]
```

you get an error because `df[,1]` has 'A' twice, so it can't be used as a rowname without modification. You use `make.names` to create rownames with unique values like this

```
unique.col1 = make.names(df[,1], unique=T)
unique.col1
```

This results in

```
"A"   "A.1" "B"
```

Note that the `.1` was added to the second `A` to make it different from the first `A`. Then define the rownames as `unique.col1`:

```
rownames(df) = unique.col1
df
```

The data.frame `df` now looks like this

```
    col1 col2
A      A    1
A.1    A    2
B      B    3
```